# Using another gem's javascript in a Rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, rails-engines

I'm trying to create a rails engine that will use javascript from a gem dependency that I have added to the engine.  However I keep getting "couldn't find file 'fullcalendar'" when I put the following line in my application.js for my engine:

```
//= require fullcalendar
```

This line is loading the javascript from the gem dependency into the rails engine.

This same line will work when the gem is installed on a normal rails app (not engine).  What am I missing here? Can an engine load javascript from another engine/gem?

**UPDATE:**
Researching on my own the issue could be that sprockets only looks for javascript inside the engine.  The gem dependency is installed into vendor/cache of the parent app NOT the engine therefore //require fullcalendar fails because it is looking within the engine and the javascript for fullcalendar is in the parent application.

What confuses me is that if I include fullcalendar in the parent application gemfile explicitly than I am able to access it in the engine.  This doesn't make sense to me.  In both instances the full calendar gems javascript  is in the parent app, but the behavior is different.  Including the gem in two places is unappelaing to me and doesn't seem like a proper solution.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I had some trouble with this in the past.

```
App > Engine 1 > Engine 2
```

Engine 1 and Engine 2 worked fine on the app. I created a dummy app in Engine 1 to test Engine 2's functionality, also worked fine. But when I put Engine 1 in App it didn't work at all.

My big mistake here was only including Engine 1 in App, Engine 2 has to be included as well!
Inheritance does not work for Gemfiles, just dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but I recently had the same issue. Here is my post to describe it the solution http://grantrklinsing.com/articles/2013/01/10/adding-3rd-party-assets-to-a-rails-gem.html. Hope it helps if you didn't get it working.

Comment: Link has been fixed

Comment: Link is broken again... Please fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Does the fullcanendar gem you're using come with an installer? Some gems come with installers for model migrations, assets, views, config files, etc.

If you're referring to the [fullcalendar-rails](https://github.com/mankind/fullcalendar-rails) gem it comes with an installer that you have to run using the 
`rails g fullcalendar:install` command.

If the gem doesn't come with an installer you can manaully clone the gem to your local machine by running `git clone gem_github_repository_url_here.git` which will enable you to navigate the gem's folders and you'll have direct access to any of the assets that the gem uses which can be copied over to your rails application.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The gem I am using is https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails which does not have an installer from what I see.  I don't want to copy the assets from the gem into my engine as that would defeat the whole purpose of using a gem for the javascript.

Comment: Did you place the gem in the assets group of your Gemfile?

Comment: The engine will contain other things besides javascript that I will want in production so I don't think assets is the correct place.  I tried it anyway and the issue was still present.

Answer (score 0):

If your Engine has a dependency added through the gemspec file, you need to require this dependency directly before Engine initialization.

`app/lib/app/engine.rb`

```
require 'fullcalendar-rails'

module App
 class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
  isolate_namespace App
 end
end
```